# How to repair the latitude and longitude that loaded from .csv and get them on the road correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, plot, geolocation

I'm trying to draw a routine using python and folium, but some of the locations are fairly far away from where they should be.

I've used the previous angle and speed to generate the next location, but it still can't get a perfect match.

Here is my code:

1. I use `pandas` to input the data which is a list collected per second.

```
    def data_input(_dir, n):
        _data = pd.read_csv(_dir + '\\_dataset\\' + n)

        return _data
```

2. Calculate the distance with two locations.

```
    def distance(location, location2):
        # 0 lat 1 lng
        radLat1 = math.radians(location[0])
        radLat2 = math.radians(location2[0])
        a = radLat1 - radLat2
        b = math.radians(location[1]) - math.radians(location2[1])
        s = 2 * math.asin(math.sqrt(math.pow(math.sin(a / 2), 2) + math.cos(radLat1) * math.cos(radLat2) * math.pow(math.sin(b/2), 2)))
        d = s * 6371.004  # km
        return d
```

3. I will call the function below if the `d` is bigger than a solid value that I set previously(like 30 or 60).
4. This is how I fix the location with substituting the next latitude and longitude. (That's not the point:-))

```
    def location_fix(location_list):  # [lat, lng, speed, angle]

        lat = location_list[0]
        lng = location_list[1]
        spd = location_list[2]
        ang = location_list[3]

        distance = spd / 3.6
        radius = 6371004
        delta = distance / radius
        theta = math.radians(ang)
        phi1 = math.radians(lat)
        lambda1 = math.radians(lng)

        sin_phi1 = math.sin(phi1)
        cos_phi1 = math.cos(phi1)
        sin_delta = math.sin(delta)
        cos_delta = math.cos(delta)
        sin_theta = math.sin(theta)
        cos_theta = math.cos(theta)

        sin_phi2 = sin_phi1 * cos_delta + cos_phi1 * sin_delta * cos_theta
        phi2 = math.asin(sin_phi2)
        y = sin_theta * sin_delta * cos_phi1
        x = cos_delta - sin_phi1 * sin_phi2
        lambda2 = lambda1 + math.atan2(y, x)

        return math.degrees(phi2), (math.degrees(lambda2) + 540) % 360 - 180
        # return the new lat and lng.
```

5. Get the list of `lat` and `lng` using `numpy`.

```
location = np.array(location)[:, [0, 1]].tolist()
```

6. Then I use folium to plot the map with the `location`.

```
    def map_g(_dir, location, n, name, color):  # generate the map

        m = folium.Map([28, 115], zoom_start=10)
        folium.PolyLine(
            location,
            weight=3,
            color=color,
            opacity=0.8
        ).add_to(m)
        m.save(os.path.join(_dir + '\\map', n + name + '.html'))
```

And here is the `csv` file sample:

```
vehicleplatenumber,device_num,direction_angle,lng,lat,acc_state,right_turn_signals,left_turn_signals,hand_brake,foot_brake,location_time,gps_speed,mileage
AA00004,AAA9101004,0,115.92313,28.651311,1,0,0,0,0,2018-08-01 00:06:38,0,5559
AA00004,AAA9101004,0,115.923106,28.651248,1,0,0,0,0,2018-08-01 00:06:39,0,5559
AA00004,AAA9101004,0,115.92310800000001,28.651248,1,0,0,0,0,2018-08-01 00:06:40,0,5559
AA00004,AAA9101004,0,115.92311000000001,28.651243,1,0,0,0,0,2018-08-01 00:06:41,0,5559
AA00004,AAA9101004,0,115.92311299999999,28.651246,1,0,0,0,0,2018-08-01 00:06:42,0,5559
AA00004,AAA9101004,0,115.923121,28.651245,1,0,0,0,0,2018-08-01 00:06:43,0,5559
AA00004,AAA9101004,0,115.92314499999999,28.651281,1,0,0,0,0,2018-08-01 00:06:44,0,5559
AA00004,AAA9101004,0,115.92317800000001,28.651346000000004,1,0,0,0,0,2018-08-01 00:06:45,0,5559
```

You can create a file using notepad and rename it with .csv for necessary test.

Comment: Well... I can think about something how to fix this.... post you code and it becomes possible to figure it out ;-) Welcome to SO. Although your question looks valid at first sight it does not meet SO [minimal site criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please modify question accordingly to [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so we both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help and I've post my code above.

Comment: Nice work. Can you also post a bit of the .cvs as text in your example (short as possible that shows all the essentials needed to help you. OR link to example if needed).

Comment: OK, I added it. Thank you :-)